# Erasing Unused disk space C drive with https://eraser.heidi.ie fills hdd and crashes

Tags: windows-7, eraser

I've used eraser from https://eraser.heidi.ie for years. This time, on a ACER pc that has been reset to factory defaults, eraser crashes near the end of the process and leaves the pc with almost no free disk space. I reset to factory again and tried it again and same fail.

Any fix for this, or a like kind very simple to configure and use program to recommend?

I attempted to join the forum for eraser but for some genius reason my account was denied, so here I am. TIA.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the HDD in question?  What version of Eraser are you using exactly?

Comment: Run Windows chkdsk before you run eraser.

Comment: Most recent eraser: Eraser 6.2.0.2982. The hdd is a 250 gb mundane hdd. I can try chkdsk.

Comment: Wow...tried a second pc that also needed was set to factory default and then ran eraser on it. Eraser nearly completed and then crashed, leaving the disk almost full. Just like the other pc.

Comment: It means eraser is a mess. Maybe it's 6.x; the other versions I used that actually worked were 5.x. What a huge waste of my time. Does anyone know of a like kind simple alternative?

Comment: On the second pc I ran chkdsk, no issues. I'm using the erase empty sections of drive or whatever the setting is, on C:.

Comment: Yep, eraser 5 works on the pcs.